# How to debug the "A technical problem with the server created an error" error?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2

I am getting following error.

> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Everywhere in my backend. I tried to recompile, flush cache and so on, nothing helps. Logs are empty, so no idea whats going on.

I watch the requests and figured that the call which causes the error looks like this:

> http://example.com/admin_uttzse/mui/index/render/key/cb27d93212d468adc094da6d1b861993a467057147331868d0b2a66a8f429c51/?namespace=notification_area&sorting%5Bfield%5D=created_at&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=asc&isAjax=true

Not sure if this helps any further. Anyone any ideas what might be wrong and how to fix that? I am running 2.2.3.

Comment: Do yu have any  3rt party extension? I suggest to do setup  upgrade, di compile  and  static content deploy  once again

Comment: Yes I have 3rd party extension. You think I should disable them all and then recompile and upgrade to see if the problem persists?

Comment: I have the same problem, this problem happened in version 2.2.3, it is really strange, try to do re index, but this will not solve the problem permanently. i found also this blog about this error , https://tutes.club/solved-magento-2-error-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-try-again-to-continue-what-you-were-doing-if-the-problem-persists-try-again-later/

Comment: Thanks WISAM! That link solved my problem ... for me it was case 3, some echo commands in index.php! THANKS!

Comment: @zexperto-WISAMHAKIM I would suggest putting your comment in to an answer, that's a p useful link i hadn't seen before

Comment: I will put it as an answer , glad  that help you

Comment: i am a Magento Developer or working on client store. after installing the Magento 2.x on client store and applying the new theme i need to change a banner. So when i go to page setting in Magento and locate the banner i want to change, click on edit image and Magento redirect me to a CMS page of image gallery. Now i am stuck here or can't load any image from my system and also can't find any image in locations. but in c-panel directory images are available. So i search-related issue on Magento office forum and also other sites but can't find the solutions for this. [The skill academy](http://t

Comment: Agree with above that you should document your solution as an answer. The link shared above has rotted, there is an [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20181206022045/https://tutes.club/solved-magento-2-error-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-try-again-to-continue-what-you-were-doing-if-the-problem-persists-try-again-later/).